# What is the meaning of Attendant risk?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of  "**attendant risk**" in below paragraph? **Tried to search already on google but no info there.**

> The crew of a given ship was naturally only concerned with how far round they were from their own particular home base. The key to knowing how far around the world you are from home is to know, at that very moment, what time it is back home.

> Up until the middle of the 18th century, navigators had been unable to determine their position at sea with accuracy and they faced the huge **attendant risks** of shipwreck or running out of supplies before reaching then destination. The angular position of Moon and other bright stars was recorded in three-hour intervals of Greenwich Time. In order to determine longitude, sailors had to measure the angle between Moon centre and a given star - lunar distance - together with height of both planets using the naval sextant.

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/attendant_2 “existing with something, or happening as a result of it”

Answer (score 2):

An "attendent risk" is a technical term from insurance, it means "a known risk you face by taking some action.

[Risk first](https://riskfirst.org/thinking/A-Simple-Scenario) gives a seanario of a person planning a party.  The attendant risks include "Ruining the cooking" or "Having the wrong ingredients".  They are risks that arise because of the action of having a party.

Similarly, there are attendant risks in going on a sea voyage, including shipwreck or running out of food.

It is a fairly technical term, but the definition was quickly found by a google search. This [glossary](https://riskfirst.org/thinking/Glossary#:%7E:text=Attendant%20Risk,the%20result%20of%20Taking%20Action.) was my top search result.